# Observable subscription only recieve the first event

Tags: angular, rxjs6, behaviorsubject

I have a few Angular components, and I use BehaviorSubject to pass event among them.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SiteManagementEventService {
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<SiteManagementEvent>(defaultEvent);   
  data = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  // publish the event using the service
  public publish(event: SiteManagementEvent) {
    if (event !== null) {
      this.messageSource.next(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Publishing events:

```
constructor (
  .......
  private eventService: SiteManagementService,
) {}
........
this.eventService.publish(event);
```

Subscribe the events:

```
constructor (
  .......
  private eventService: SiteManagementService,
) {}

onInit() {
  ......
  this.eventService.data.subscribe(event => {console.log("event received"});
}
```

By having the above, the issue is that only one receiving component (I have multiple receiving components) receives one event, and do not receive any following events.

Anything I did wrong? Any online samples for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using BehaviorSubject correctly. It will replay the last emitted value to new subscriptions.

Ensure that your service is a singleton by using `@Injectable({provideIn: "root"})`.